# How do you transform a Point[] to ArrayOfPoint in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, wsimport

I am importing a wsdl file using wsimport from a .net service and getting ArrayOfXXX. What is the recommended way of converting from java collections to these objects?

Take a Position object (representing a point on the map). The wsdl I have is as such:

```
<xs:complexType name="PositionList"> 
  <xs:sequence> 
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Positions" type="s0:ArrayOfPosition" /> 
  </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType>
```

Try and `wsimport` this in Java and you will get an `ArrayOfPoint` object.

How do you transform a `Point[]` to an `ArrayOfPoint`?

Comment: More details here: [ws-i Profiles](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1.html#soapenc_Array)

Comment: See also http://tinyurl.com/so-hints.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Yes, this is the question I was trying to get an answer for.

Comment: @Robert Harvey I see your point - I thought quoting the previous question would be enough. But I still believe it is a valid question and would have been happy to clarify if anyone commented.

Answer (score 0):

If your `ArrayOfPoint` class has a protected member `_list` which is a `List<Point>`, then you could derive your own class - let's call it `MyArrayOfPoint` with a Constructor that takes a `Point[]`. In that constructor you make the `Point[]` a `List<Point>` and set `_list`.

I had a similar case with ArrayOfLong once...